# Unable to download my own beta on TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight, beta

I'm having a problem with TestFlight. I have an app on the AppStore, and I have always launched the beta on TestFlight first, tested the app for a while, and then released it. However, with the latest beta I launched, it doesn't let me download it because it says "The requested app is not available or it doesn't exist".

I made some research and some said that it needed to be approved for sale (which I thought was strange, the two things should not be related), and I sent it to be approved. Now it has been approved and the status is "waiting to be released", but I still cannot download it.

Has anyone already experienced something like this?

If it may be useful information, I am developing with Xcode 13.1, the minimum required iOS version I set on my app is iOS 14, and I am trying to download it on my iPhone 12 with iOS 15.1, on which the AppStore version works perfectly, but I can't download the TestFlight version. [Here's some screenshot from the AppStoreConnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wouUu.jpg).

Thanks

[image]