# Testflight Internal Testing Error - "Could not download app"

Tags: ios, xcode, expo, app-store-connect, testflight

Have a similar problem to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909888/unable-to-download-my-own-beta-on-testflight) - we have a build on Testflight. The status in the Build tab shows "testing" with green checkmark. We are trying to do internal testing. However, when we open testflight and try to install the app, it throws the error "Could not download {app} The requested app is not available or doesn't exist".

This is a version 1.0 app which is still under review in the app store. My understanding that that should have no bearing.

Has anyone encountered this before? The posts I see elsewhere with this error are for external testers or changes in sale status.

Thanks in advance.